# How do you set multiple Flags in the Python GLib?

Tags: python-3.x, glib

I'm currently trying to control the mpv music player on Linux using GLib to spawn the process. 
To watch if it terminated, I have to use the `watch_child()` method which requires that you set various flags. However the Lib doesn't accept a list of flags. How do you do it then?

```
self.mpv, _, self.output, self.fehler = GLib.spawn_async(["mpv", '--no-video', link], \
    flags=GLib.SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it, you just `or` them with `|` like in C

Comment: Glad you figured it out. For better control over the spawned process, you may find [`Gio.Subprocess`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio//2.52/GSubprocess.html) easier to use than `GLib.spawn_async()`.